# How to publish a Web Service over HTTPS with JAX-WS in an OSGi container?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, osgi

With Java it is easy to consume a Web Service over HTTPS but how do you publish one?

The standard JAX-WS implementation doesn't support it. We tried Jetty but Jetty does not have support for Web Services over HTTPS either (`JettyHttpServerProvider`'s `createHttpsServer()` throws an `UnsupportedOperatonException`). I think this problem should be really easy. But somehow I always run against walls.

Additionally **this has to work with OSGi** so I'd prefer if most or all dependencies are available as bundles. Currently I try to get CXF running but it has a lot of non-OSGi dependencies which makes deployment very hard.

We also need client authentication via certificates but my hope is this will be relatively easy once HTTPS is enabled.

Why is this such a big deal? For example to provide static content with Jetty, all you need to do is create a server, add any SSL connector and you're done. Why can't it be that easy for Web Services?

Comment: Don't those same Jetty steps for protecting static content also protect your web service?  It shouldn't matter what content type is getting hosted.

Comment: @Pace: No, it doesn't work because the WSDL points to the wrong endpoint (and to the wrong schema file for that matter): It links http instead of https.

Comment: Ok, seriously. Nobody needs to publish over HTTPS with JAX-WS? Am I the only person in the world with this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our system uses cxf and jetty in OSGi, and it works fine with HTTPS.

When you publish your service to WebService, you should not concern it is HTTP or HTTPS. Configure your jetty to support HTTPS by passing the following properties to OSGi:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.http.enabled=false
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.https.enabled=true
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.https.port=443
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.ssl.keystore=...
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.ssl.password=...
```

You can check out the other properties in

```
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_2.0.0.v20100503.jar\OSGI-INF\metatype\config.xml
```

By doing this, you can try to use IE to access the wsdl of your service through https.

Comment: Could you outline how you deploy CXF in an OSGi container? I spent a few days in dependency hell and I'm on the verge of giving up. The little information I found via Google says that it's very difficult to get all dependencies right.

Comment: You need to create a bundle containing cxf jars and export cxf packages. You will know how many jar files you need in the file "WHICH_JAR".

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring, you could use the following configuration.  This [article on FuseSource](http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.0/security/i486101.html#i488847) gives a good explanation of steps needed for configuration.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" 
  xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration" 
  xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-
jetty/configuration" 
  xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" 
  xsi:schemaLocation=" 
       http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security       http: 
//cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd 
            http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration
            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-
2.0.xsd"> 


  <http:destination name="{http://package}AnInterfacePort.http- 
destination"> 
  </http:destination> 

  <httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf"> 
   <httpj:engine port="9001"> 
    <httpj:tlsServerParameters> 
      <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password"> 
           <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" 
                file="C:/certs/cherry.jks"/> 
      </sec:keyManagers> 
      <sec:trustManagers> 
          <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" 
               file="C:/certs/truststore.jks"/> 
      </sec:trustManagers> 
      <sec:cipherSuitesFilter> 
        <!-- these filters ensure that a ciphersuite with 
          export-suitable or null encryption is used, 
          but exclude anonymous Diffie-Hellman key change as 
          this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks --> 
        <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include> 
        <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include> 
        <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include> 
        <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include> 
        <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude> 
      </sec:cipherSuitesFilter> 
      <sec:clientAuthentication want="true" required="true"/> 
    </httpj:tlsServerParameters> 
   </httpj:engine> 
  </httpj:engine-factory> 


  <!-- We need a bean named "cxf" --> 
  <bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl"/> 
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to find out about HTTPS in CXF in a simple Java program. My problem is still with integrating it into an OSGi container. We don't use Spring.